# Sumproducts of staggered ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble finding a solution to an excel problem involving sumproducts.  I want to do a staggered sum, where the items being multiplied do not necessarily line up in the same position in their respective ranges.

So if the data are arranged monthly in rows, they would look like:

```
a1  a2  a3  a4

x1  x2  x3  x4
```

Then my solution in month n would be:

n=1:  (a1x1)

n=2: (a1x2)+(a2x1)

n=3: (a1x3)+(a2x2)+(a3x1)

n=4: (a1x4)+(a2x3)+(a3x2)+(a4x1)

I know I'm able to do this if I separate out the calculations into separate rows, but I'd like to solve this in one formula if possible to conserve space, as I'm doing this for at least 60 months.  Also, I'm not necessarily tied to using a sumproduct, I just thought that would be the most applicable method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I think what I've realized is that if I can flip the second range to be in reverse order, that would solve my problem.  So it'd be a sumproduct of the first range and the second range in reverse order,  but still am not sure how to accomplish that second piece.

Comment: You can probably get some milage with `INDEX()`, `COLUMN()` `ROW()`, and `INDIRECT()` but I don't know if I understand your problem. There would be a ton of self referencing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is hideous, but it does seem to work:

If you have your "**n**" values 1 through 60 listed out in the range `A4:A63`, you just need to enter the following formula into `B4` then drag it down to `B63`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1)&":"&ADDRESS(1,A4)),N(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,1)&":"&ADDRESS(2,A4)),0,A4-COLUMN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,1)&":"&ADDRESS(2,A4))))))`

This also assumes you have your "**a**" values in row 1 (starting at A1) and your "**x**" values in row 2 (starting at A2).

Comment: plus one :D you beat me to it.